# "HTTPS required" while logging in to Keycloak as admin

Tags: jboss7.x, keycloak

[image]

I am using `Keycloak (version 1.0.4.Final)` in `JBOSS AS 7.1.1` server. The server is on Amazon AWS.

I am able to start the jboss server with keycloak. i can see the keycloak default screen while hitting the URL - `ServerIP:8080/auth`

But when i am clicking on the `Administration Console`link to go to the login screen. I am getting a page saying - `HTTPS required`

The server is on AWS, changing to `"ssl-required" : "none",`
in General Adapter Config has not helped.

How to resolve this issue?

Edit: I was not getting this issue in keycloak-1.2.0.Beta1 version.

Comment: Put note here, because most answers are focusing to disable ssl, which is totally in wrong direction. Jump to read the answer with port 8443

Answer (score 60):

I was running the key cloak inside a docker container, The keycloak command line tool was avaialble inside the keycloak container.

```
docker exec -it {contaierID} bash
cd keycloak/bin
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

If the admin user is not created, then the user can be created via this command.

```
./add-user-keycloak.sh --server http://ip_address_of_the_server:8080/admin --realm master --user admin --password adminPassword
```

---

Update:
For the newer versions the file in available in the following path: `/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin`

Comment: `kubectl exec -it keycloak-0 -- /bin/bash` to get into container if anyone's using the Kubernetes Helm Chart

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get `HTTPS required [invalid_request]`.

Comment: For the newer versions the file in available in the following path: `/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin`

Comment: @NirojanSelvanathan, your comment saves my day.. I can't find the keycloak folder in docker container. Thanks

Comment: @NirojanSelvanathan your method works, pls update the comment details [regarding the newer versions] in the Answer itself. Thanks

Comment: i get [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=LOGIN_ERROR after doing this

Comment: @NirojanSelvanathan Thanks.Saved a lot of time for creating just a test system on EC2.

Comment: for keycloak 18+

`cd /opt/keycloak/bin/`

then don't use `\auth`, so the command will look like 

`./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 --realm master --user admin`

and then

`./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE`

Comment: for keycloack 21+

following thread worked for me 

bash-5.1$ cd ~/bin/ 
bash-5.1$./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user admin
bash-5.1$ ./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE --server http://localhost:8080

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70577004/keycloak-could-not-find-resource-for-full-path

Answer (score 50):

If you want to disable it for your realm and have no possibility to use UI, do it directly on the database:

```
update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where id = 'master';
```

Note - Restart keycloak for effect

Comment: If you have only SSH access and Keycloak is running with embedded DB, you may use native DB client, e.g. for H2: java -cp <PATH TO H2>.jar org.h2.tools.Shell -url "jdbc:h2:file:<your DB>" -user <USER> -password <PASSWORD> -sql "update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where id = 'master'"

Comment: One also has to restart keycloak after doing this.

Comment: i get [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=LOGIN_ERROR after doing this

Comment: Using kcadm cli is the better solution and does not require a restart

Comment: @VladimirSalin Error: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: The database is read only; SQL statement: after executing update query. I used default username and password as "sa" , "sa"

Comment: if you have quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:21 image, you can use this SQL script:

UPDATE realm SET ssl_required='NONE' where name = 'master';

Comment: I did this and now login works. But the authentication flow still fails. It says  "HTTPS required". Can I complete an auth flow with http or no ?

Comment: dumb mistake... I changed the setting in the db for the master and then proceded to create a new realm, and did not set it on this new realm. 

It is working now

Answer (score 21):

You can use the keycloak command line admin tool to change the setting as long as it can authenticate to a local IP address. You can temporarily launch Keycloak on localhost to make this change.

```
kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
kcadm.sh update realms/realmname -s sslRequired=NONE
```

Obviously, make sure to replace realm names, username, port, etc as required.

For more information on getting started with the Admin CLI, see documentation: [Server Administration: Admin CLI](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#admin-cli)

Comment: this is a better solution as it is not required to restart Keycloak (a docker container) in my case

Comment: running `./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user username` helped

Answer (score 18):

This is quite old and now on release versions (I am using Keycloak 1.9.3 demo / Developer bundle), however to save some poor soul some time....

Keycloak now defaults to HTTPS for all external IP addresses.  Unfortunately, from what I can tell the Wildfly instance that comes with the demo bundle does NOT support HTTPS.  Makes for a pretty insane default if you're installing Keycloak on a remote machine as there is effectively no way to access the Keycloak admin console out of the box.

At this point, you have two options; 1) Install HTTPS in Wildfly or 2) Tunnel via SSH into the remote machine and proxy your browser through it, go to the admin console and turn off the SSL requirement (Realm Settings -> Login -> Require SSL).  This works because SSL is not required for local connections.

Remember to first create the admin user by going to $KEYCLOAK_HOME/keycloak/bin and running ./add-user-keycloak -r master -u <> -p <>.  This add user script is not interactive like the Wildfly add user script is, you need to put it all on the command line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: what is the second option?

Comment: The 2nd option is to tunnel into the remote machine.  I updated my answer so it's clear.

Answer (score 11):

It's a bit late but I'm sure people will find this useful. If you are using docker to run keycloak, instead of forwarding port 8080, forward 8443 and it works like charm.

```
docker run -p 8443:8443 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=username -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=password jboss/keycloak
```

Comment: you have to access https[://]URL:8443. if still doesn't work, try downgrading the version of keycloak

Comment: the methd proposed by @Nirojan Selvanathan is working fine

Comment: Works with latest version 15.x. Try `docker run -d --name keycloak -p 8443:8443 -e KEYCLOAK_USER=admin -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin -e DB_VENDOR=h2 quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:15.0.1` Keycloak will auto-generate self-signed certificates. Access your site using HTTPS. Example - `https://your-hostname:8443/auth/`

Comment: This should be the accept answer, more than to avoid ssl setup by other solutions. By the way google chrome blocks you to access url `https://your-hostname-keycloak:8443`, switch to use other browsers , such as Safari

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to bin folder `cd /opt/keycloak/bin/`

and then run this command to disable ssl on realm "master"

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://x.x.x.x:8080 --realm master --user admin

./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

Answer (score 1):

I testing in docker keycloak: 
probe that: Realm Settings -> Login -> Require SSL and put in off.
or docker exec YOUR_DOCKER_NAME /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect \ "/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default:read-resource"

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying keycloak on kubernetes you can try setting up following ENV VAR

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: keycloak
    env:
    - name:  PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
      value: "true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a complete working docker-compose:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:latest
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - DB_VENDOR=mysql
      - DB_ADDR=db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_DATABASE=keycloak
      - DB_USER=keycloak
      - DB_PASSWORD=example
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
      - "9990:9990"
  db:
    image: mysql:5
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ../data-keycloak:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3309:3306"
```

and then, execute in db:

```sql
update REALM set ssl_required='NONE' where name = 'master';
```

Of course, this is not for production unless you're using in a safe environment.

Comment: For me the postgress db name was `realm` case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect the keycloak database and update the table

```
update REALM set ssl_required='EXTERNAL' where name = 'master';
```

then restart docker

```
docker compose restart
```

Answer (score 0):

for keycloack 21+ following thread worked for me when I added http:// in front of `server`

```
cd ~/bin/ 
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user admin 
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE --server http://localhost:8080
```