# Keycloak docker HTTPS-REQUIRED with nginx ssl

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, proxy, keycloak

I am using `keycloak` for production for the first time. I run keycloak on my local machine and never faced this issue. First I am using docker to run keycloak server. The docker image is pulled from `jboss/keycloak`. I have set up my `SSL` using `letsEncrypt` on my domain `test.com`

After running the docker image I ended up getting error `HTTPS-REQUIRED` when I click on administrative console. After reading up a lot about this from [HERE](http://piotrnowicki.com/java/2017/01/09/keycloak-docker-with-ssl-proxy/) [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622599/https-required-while-logging-in-to-keycloak-as-admin) and [HERE](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2952) I realized I need SSL on my domain which I did.

I also pass `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true` in my docker command. This is how I run it.

```
docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=temp -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=temp -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true -p 9090:8080 jboss/keycloak
```

My NGINX server block looks like

```
  map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
    default                    off;
    text/html                  epoch; #means no cache, as it is not a static page
    text/css                   max;
    application/javascript     max;
    application/woff2          max;
    ~image/                    30d; #it is only the logo, so maybe I could change it once a month now
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


    location /auth/ {
            proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:9090/auth/;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;

          proxy_set_header Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }  


        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    # SSL configuration
    #

    #listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server; # does not work properly with Angular, TODO research about this
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    expires $expires;

    include snippets/ssl-test.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

}
```

By setting up ssl everytime I go to text.com or www.test.com it has https. But when I do test.com:9090 it says not secure. So I try IP:9090 which works but without https.

Now every time I go to IP:9090 I can see the main page of keycloak but after I click on administrative console I get HTTPS - REQUIRED error. What am I missing in my configuration or setting up keycloak/ssl/nginx config?

mostly followed this [setup nginx for production](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-configure-nginx-in-production-to-serve-angular-app-and-reverse-proxy-nodejs)

EDIT::
 Move the location /auth/ from first to second server block and it works. Thought it would be helpful.

Comment: You can answer your own question. This will mark your question as answered and give you, as a reward, reputation points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct structure

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test.com www.test.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }





        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    # SSL configuration
    #

    #listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    #listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server; # does not work properly with Angular, TODO research about this
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    expires $expires;
    location /auth/ {
            proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x:9090/auth/;

          proxy_http_version 1.1;

          proxy_set_header Host               $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    }  
    include snippets/ssl-test.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

}
```

Comment: I get 404, Are you sure it works? I should replace http://x.x.x.x... by localhost or domain name?