# How to use the command kcadm.sh when after successfull login it says HTTPS required in Keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I am trying also to disable HTTPS, based on a stackoverflow question, an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56170579/19384556) was
to

```
docker exec -it {contaierID} bash
cd keycloak/bin
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master --user admin
./kcadm.sh update realms/master -s sslRequired=NONE
```

but after executing the third command I am getting the error of HTTPS Required
[Image](https://prnt.sc/1cgSZp7xPsKI)

Version 19.0.2 of Keycloak